# How to setup grunt-ssh file paths to sftp?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

Im trying to use this plugin:
https://github.com/andrewrjones/grunt-ssh

But I cant figure out how to setup the paths correctly:

```
  "./": "../../js/us/common/**"
```

What does the "./" refer to?

Comment: `./` refers to the current directory; `../` refers to the directory above the one you are currently looking inside of.